# Set size of ACS Kubernetes Master

Tags: azure, azure-cli

Is there a way to set the size of the Azure Container Service Kubernetes Master?

It's possible to specify a agent count and size through the azure-cli. However, I can only find a way to set the count for the Master nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can achieve that using [acs-engine](https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine). It has the ability to generate ARM templates for your deployments of ACS resources, there you can specify the Master VM size using the cluster definition file:

https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/blob/master/docs/acsengine.md#generating-a-template

there is also a help document for that file:

https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/blob/master/docs/clusterdefinition.md

Comment: Do you know if "azure-cli acs create" is a wrapper for the acs-engine? I tried to just manually change the VM size in Azure Portal and I'm gonna evaluate the long term effects of doing that.

Comment: well, looking at the [source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-cli/master/src/command_modules/azure-cli-acs/azure/cli/command_modules/acs/custom.py) it appears that the master VM size is not specified, so it is using the Azure Container Service default (so it seems). And no, looks like its not a wrapper for that, it just calls an ARM Template to deploy the Kubernetes cluster (look at the `_create_kubernetes` method)

Comment: You're right. I was hoping to use the cli instead of running a dedicated tool. I'm curious as to why Azure releases two tools that do the same thing... acs-engine seems to have more options, so I guess that's the better way for ACS.

Comment: well, acs is still in early stages of its life, i bet things will get better in the future

Comment: Actually, after reading more of the documentation acs-engine is used to create templates for azure-cli to consume. So acs-engine is not a wrapper but a helper.

Comment: yeah, but I believe it happens on Azure side, is it not? acs engine requires go, so it can't possibly run without it? or are you talking about node cli, not python cli? node cli requires that, iirc

Answer (score 2):

Using the `--master-vm-size` will be helpful.

```
az acs create -n "your-kubernetes-cluster" -g your-resource-group --master-vm-size Standard_A2 --agent-count 2 --agent-vm-size Standard_A1 --dns-prefix kube --orchestrator-type kubernetes --debug
```

Comment: Didn't know they added that, thanks. However, in my case I'm in westeurope and this is only available in "ukwest, uksouth, westcentralus, westus2, canadaeast, canadacentral, westindia, southindia, centralindia"

Answer (score 0):

Highlighting some differences between [ACS RP](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-service/) (cli talks to the managed service) and [ACS Engine](https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine)

**Azure Container Service** is an SLA-backed Azure service with features in the Azure portal, Azure command-line tools, and Azure APIs. The service enables you to quickly implement and manage clusters running standard container orchestration tools with a relatively small number of configuration choices.

**ACS Engine** is an open-source project that enables power users to customize the cluster configuration at every level. This ability to alter the configuration of both infrastructure and software means that we offer no SLA for ACS Engine. Support is handled through the open-source project on GitHub rather than through official Microsoft channels.

ACS Engine has more features e.g. custom VNET, multiple agent pools (and the ability of have Windows and Linux agent pools run side by side in the same cluster if the orchestrator supports it) compared to ACS  managed service that supports only one agent pool. Some of these features will eventually make it to ACS managed service (also driven by customer demand) but some might continue to remain only in ACS Engine.

One other thing to note is that if you created your cluster using Azure Container Service you will see an additional resource of type Microsoft.ContainerService in your resource group but in case of clusters created using ACS Engine such a resource won't be present.